# Is it possible to replicate the Override Annotation from Java in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, overriding

I know that in Java, the Override annotation checks if the superclass has the method:

```
class Animal {
  public void speak () {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
  }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  @override
  public void eat () { //this kind of stuff
    System.out.println("omnomnom");
  }
}
```

is there a way to do this in Ruby (as a function or something)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works, but it's a little verbose:

```
class OverrideError < StandardError
    def initialize a
        super("the superclass of `#{a[0]}`(`#{a[0].superclass}`) does not contain the method that has been attempeted to Override: `#{a[1]}`")
    end
end

#this function help the _override_ function ignore string literals
def delQ str
    str = str.gsub(/(".*"|'.*'|\%[qQ]?\{.*\})/, "")
    while /\= ?\<\<\-?[\w\_\?\!]+ /.match?(str)
        x = /\= ?\<\<\-?[\w\_\?\!]+ /.match(str)[0]
        stopname = x.sub(/\= ?\<\<\-?/, "")
        locat = str =~ /\= ?\<\<\-?[\w\_\?\!]+ .*/
        part = str.slice(locat)
        stop = part =~ %r{stopname}
        part1 = part.sub(%r{x + ".*" + stopname}, "")
        str = str.sub(part, part1)
    end
    return str
end

def _override_
    file = File.read("./" + caller[0][/[^:]+/]).split("\n")
    loc = (caller[0].to_s.scan(/\d+/).first).to_i
    line = file[loc]
    method = /def (self(\.|::))?[\w\_\?\!]+/.match(line)[0]
    method = method.gsub(/(def|self|\.|::|\s)/, "")
    clname = ""
    file = file.join("\n")
    file = delQ(file)
    file = file.split("\n")
    while loc >= 0
        substr = file[loc].gsub(/(\t|\n)/, "")
        if substr.start_with?("class ")
            clname = file[loc].gsub(/\t/, "").sub("class ", "")
            clname = /[\w_\?\!]+/.match(clname)[0]
            break
        end
        loc -= 1
    end
    clname = Kernel.const_get(clname)
    hmm = clname.superclass.method_defined?(method.to_sym)
    unless hmm
        raise OverrideError, [clname, method]
    end
end
```

A demonstration on how this will be used:

```
class Animal
    def initialize name
        @name = name
    end
    def speak
        puts "Hello!"
    end
end
class Dog < Animal
    def initialize name
        super name
    end
    _override_
    def speak
        # no error
        puts "woof!"
    end
    _override_ 
    def eat


#Traceback (most recent call last):
#   2: from main.rb:11:in `<main>'
#   1: from main.rb:19:in `<class:Dog>'
#/home/runner/Annotations/override.rb:41:in `_override_': the superclass #of `Dog`(`Animal`) does not contain the method that has been attempted #to Override: `eat` (OverrideError)


        puts "omnomnom"
    end
end
```

Comment: `File.read` nobody promised there is the file. Also, ruby classes _are open_ and the definition of the method might appear anywhere in any required file with any name.

Comment: I don't understand: "nobody promised there is the file". also, this is assuming you define your class methods like regular people do, without using `class.send(:define_method, foo_bar)` or similar tricks.

Comment: The good code must work in REPL when there is no source file, as well as with all the ways the method might be defined.

Comment: most normal people do not define important classes inside the REPL part, and even if they do, you could _certainly_ do something simpler, but the idea of this one is that it works almost like Java's `@override`, on any class.

Comment: No it does not. Java is a compiled language, unlike ruby. The easiest way to have users of your code to hate you would be to imply limitations like above. Anyone reopening the class to add new functions should not suffer from that neither you nor the answer poster barely understand how ruby works and what it was designed for.

Comment: are you saying Ruby just shouldn't have an @override? your argument is quite confusing; The above code works, isn't that %90+ of what matters as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

That would be relatively easy with a class method defined on the top-level eigenclass.

```rb
class Animal
  def speak; :ok; end

  def self.override *ms
    ms = ms - Animal.instance_methods
    puts "⚠️ #{ms.inspect} method(s) missing " \
         "in #{self}’s ancestors" unless ms.empty?
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  override :speak
  def speak; :ok; end

  override :eat
  def eat; :ok; end
end
```

The above would print

```rb
# ⚠️ [:eat] method(s) missing in Dog’s ancestors
```

The call to `override` here is similar to call to [`Module#module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function) with an argument and might be placed anywhere in the code, accepting as many method names as needed.

It might be also accomplished with eigenclass instance variable to make it look more like java version.

```rb
class Animal
  def speak
    :ok
  end

  def self.inherited(base)
    base.instance_variable_set(:@override, ->(*ms) {
      ms = ms - Animal.instance_methods
      puts "⚠️ #{ms.inspect} method(s) without super" \
        unless ms.empty?
    })
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  @override[:speak]
  def speak; :ok; end

  @override[:eat]
  def eat; :ok; end
end
```

---

It is also possible to *fully* replicate Java syntax with a help of [`TracePoint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html) and/or [`Module#method_added`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-method_added) but I find it less explicit and would avoid in favor of direct method name passing as shown above.

Comment: That' s really clever.

Comment: A method definition expression evaluates to a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method being defined. Therefore, you can also write `override def speak; end`. You should change `override` to return its arguments, that way, you can then also write something like `private override def speak; end`.

Comment: I wanted to replicate to be as similar as possible to the Java's `@override`, but that's a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to throw in this old gist (of mine) that implements the behavior:

https://gist.github.com/kares/7434811

Can be used with an argument `override :foo` or simply as a tag for next method:

```rb
  class Bar
    include Override

    def foo(msg); end
  end

  class Baz < Bar
    override
    def foo(msg); super; end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking the [answer of Aleksei Matiushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195355/3982562), you could make this more reusable by moving it into a module.

```
module Overridable
  def override(*methods)
    diff = methods - superclass.instance_methods
    return if diff.empty?
    puts "⚠ #{diff.inspect} method(s) missing from #{superclass}"
  end
end
```

You can extend the module in the base class `Animal`, this way all subclasses inheriting from `Animal` have the `override` method. Or you could choose to only extend a specific subclass.

```
class Animal
  # make :override available in all subclasses
  extend Overridable
end
```

Or assuming the above isn't set.

```
class Dog < Animal
  # make :override available in only this subclass
  extend Overridable
end
```

Comment: What's the point of making a module out of just one function? it doesn't make it "more reusable"/

Comment: Say you have the classes `Vehicle` and `Car` where you would like the same behaviour. You can simply extend the module. When this method is added to the class `Animal`, you'll have to let `Vehicle` inherit from `Animal`, which I find a weird thing to do.

Comment: The other answers don't require any mixins, they allow it to work wherever it's used, otherwise you could just manually put in the name of the class and its superclass.

Comment: @Rhodochrosite-613 Because the [answer of user12132075](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58194732/3982562) defines a method in the global namespace. The [answer of Aleksei Matiushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195355/3982562) only works as long as you're inheriting from `Animal`.

Comment: I don't understand why it would matter regarding the global namespace, do you want it to throw an error if it no class is found or a class is found that has no superclasses?_________ Also, fine, but why mention "reusability" rather than "necessity"?